# PDF controls render text differently

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I'm working on a website that creates pdfs dynamically.

I've been playing around with two different pdf controls- [wpcubed](http://www.wpcubed.com/products/pdfcontrol/index.htm) and [abcpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm), and was surprised to see that they both appear to render text differently.

wpCubed:

[image]

abcpdf:

[image]

They are both using arial 25pt bold, so I was expecting them to look identical. Can anyone explain why they don't.

Here are the full files: [wpCubed](http://www.box.net/shared/1c72oiaykl) , [abcpdf](http://www.box.net/shared/iq46pxcrgl)

Comment: It is possible that they used different zoom levels / dpi when rendering the text.

Comment: The zoom level of the pdf viewer is definitely the same. I made sure I checked that.

Comment: The zoom level actually depends on the reference dpi used for 100% zoom. For example Adobe Reader can use 110 dpi (or other custom values that can be set in Preferences) as reference for 100% zoom, so 100% zoom in Adobe Reader will not be the same like 100% zoom in Foxit. If you can post the file somewhere, I can take a look at it. Our company also develops a PDF viewer, PDFView4NET (http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm), you are welcomed to take a look at it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Files are there now.

Comment: wpcubed.pdf uses Arial Bold font, size 22.5 points and it also adjusts the word spacing. abcpdf.pdf uses Arial font, size 25, no word spacing adjustment and it draws the same text 4 times, each time shifting the X position with 0.25 points (I have no idea why).  I recommend also to take a look at our PDF generator PDF4NET: www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm

Comment: That's extremely helpful. How did you find that out? I've had a look at your pdf generator- it looks like it would do the job too. Thank you so much!

Comment: I looked inside the page content using our tool PDFXplorer. It is a low level PDF viewer, it displays raw objects in the PDF file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several different possibilities:

1. Zoom levels in your view of the PDF.  If your default view is fit width, and the default page size differs, this could happen quite subtly.
2. Kerning.  The spacing between two characters can be adjusted depending on what those characters are.  In "Ti" the "i" is often much closer to the "T" than it might otherwise be.  If one supports it and the other doesn't, your output will have different widths.
3. Ligatures.  The classic example is "fi", where the dot of the i and the overhang of the "f" are the same pixels.  If one supports it and the other doesn't, your output will have different widths.
4. Paths vs fonts.  It's possible to draw a given string of text using text operators or line-to/curve-to operators.  The later is wildly inefficient, but sometimes the only way to correctly draw a given piece of text.  The pathed text might suffer from a lack of font "hinting"... various tricks used in an effort to get text to line up with pixels.

Without access to your PDF outputs it's impossible to be sure.

Having said that, the aspect ratios of several of those characters *Looks Different*.  Compare the "e" in "test" from the two strings.  The "e" from abcpdf looks 'wider' than the one from wbCubed.  That's not kerning, ligatures, or zoom levels.  It might not even be paths vs fonts.

So can we see your PDFs?

---

Here's the content stream from wpcubed

```
    
    BT 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm
    /F1 22.500 Tf 0 Ts  0 g -2.667 Tw 452 -18 Td(This is a test)Tj
    ET
```

And here's the content stream from abcpdf:

```
    BT
    0 0 0 rg
    /Fabc5 25 Tf
    1 0 0 1 444.825 822 Tm
    (This is a test) Tj
    0.25 0 Td
    (This is a test) Tj
    0.25 0 Td
    (This is a test) Tj
    0.25 0 Td
    (This is a test) Tj
    ET
```

Heh: "Poor man's bold".  Let me check the font resources...  Yep.

wpcubed is using "Arial,bold".  abcpdf is using "ArialMT", and printing the same words with a tiny offset several times.

You can probably convince abcpdf to use "Arial,bold" in which case I'd expect the two outputs to look identical.  I haven't looked at abcpdf before, but it's probably possible.

I just checked their docs, and it looks like `XFont.findFamily("Arial")` would be the way to go.  You'd check the array of returned `XFonts` for one that's 'really' Arial Bold, rather than some faux bolding technique with a normal Arial.  You probably want to look at `XFont.names` rather than `XFont.name` as well.

That particular "make it look bold" trick has a Serious Drawback:  Copy-n-paste will pick up all 4 instances of the text.  A more selection-friendly method is to define a line thickness based on some small fraction of the font's point size (iText uses 1/30), and both stroke and fill the font.  Fonts are normally just filled, so the thickness of that line is added to the outside of the font, with no extra words to trip up someone selecting/screen reading the text.

Yow.  Blind folks with screen readers must hate that.

Comment: Thanks. Zoom levels are definitely the same- I checked that. The others are possibilities I'll look into.

Comment: I've added links to the pdfs.

Comment: Thank you. I've now changed from using "Arial" with bold to "Arial Bold". And it works. (Also it gets my whites doubly clean!)